# How to give a user temporary access to edit integration stream elements in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

Currently Integration Stream of all the projects in our ClearCase setup can be edited only by admin users.

But now we have a requirement to give a user temporary permission to edit some contents in Integration Stream.

When he tried to edit the contents, he was prevented for doing so by a `NOINACT` trigger, which prevents the user from creating activities on the integration stream.

Is there a way to temporarily disable this trigger in a particular project, stream or vob of for a particular user?
Is there any other method to give a user temporary edit privilege to integration stream ?

---

As per VonC's instruction, I tried to add the user to the excluded list of users, using `mktrtype` command.
Please find below the command I tried to execute:

```
cleartool mktrtype -replace -c [comment] -ucmobject -nusers [list of user ids] -preop mkactivity -execwin [windows trigger.pl location] -execunix [unix trigger.pl location]
```

But I am getting the error cleartool:

```
type not specified error.
```

Can you please help troubleshoot that new error message?

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the [`mktrtype` documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm), you should see the option -nusers.

Simply add his login to the list.

```
-nus/ers login-name[,...]
```

> Suppresses trigger firing when any user on the comma-separated login-name list performs the operation.

You can edit that list through the type explorer, allowing you to deactivate that trigger temporarily for a specific user, while maintaining said trigger active for everyone else.

You will find the list on the tab "Firing Conditions":

[image: Firing Conditions]

If that GUI was unresponsive for some reason, then your best bet is to recreate that `mktrtype` command, with the addition user added to the `-nuser` option, and with the **`-replace`** option.
See [this thread](http://dbaspot.com/configuration-management/193380-clearcase-trigger-question-modifying-nuser-list-trigger-type.html) for an example.
You don't need to reinstall (`mktrigger`) the updated trigger after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I was trying to exclude user using type explorer, but in trigger properties - excluded users list, I cant find the option to add new users. can you please help?

Comment: I have updated my question with the command, I tried to execute, to add the user's id to the excluded list of users. But I am keep getting an error. Please help

Comment: @aquero you are missing at the end the extended name with a type selector of your trigger: `trtype:name@\pvob` (`trtype` is the type selector for a trigger, followed by the name of said trigger whose definition your are replacing, and its pvob or "project vob").

Comment: @aquero: if you have any other error message, copy-paste the command and its output in a comment. I will debug it.